# Cron Jobs error in cPanel

Tags: cron, cpanel

I'm not at all familiar with linux commands. Anyways, coming to the main point here. I recently bought a hosting service. Everything is set but as soon as I click on Cron Jobs, I'm getting an error.

It reads as follow:

> The system cannot update the /var/cpanel/sysinfo.config file because it cannot determine your distribution's major version. Run the following command: rpm -qf --queryformat '%{VERSION}\n' /etc/redhat-release Output other than the numbers 5 or 6 indicates a problem. Open a support ticket or resolve the issue manually.

Then, there are 4 more errors. All are similar to following:

> A warning occurred while processing this directive. 
>   Use of uninitialized value $rpm_arch in scalar chomp at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 157.
>    at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 157.
>       Cpanel::GenSysInfo::_get_rpm_arch() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 93
>       Cpanel::GenSysInfo::_get_new_conf(HASH(0x5a30af8)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 36
>       Cpanel::GenSysInfo::run() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/GenSysInfo.pm line 57
>       Cpanel::GenSysInfo::get_rpm_distro_version() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Cron.pm line 523
>       Cpanel::Cron::crontab_perms() called at cpanel.pl line 3003
>       main::docron("crontab_perms", ARRAY(0x5a2eb98)) called at cpanel.pl line 2056
>       eval {...} called at cpanel.pl line 2056
>       main::_api1("Cron", "cron", "crontab_perms()", "crontab_perms", ARRAY(0x5a2eb98), "safe_html_encode", undef, undef) called at cpanel.pl line 1728
>       main::real_exectag("") called at cpanel.pl line 4105
>       main::dotag_finished_headers(0) called at cpanel.pl line 3964
>       main::cpanel_parseblock("\x{a}

Please, let me know if you need more details. I contacted their customer service and I'm yet receive an answer from them.

Comment: Thats it's a error of server. Your hosting provider must be correct servers problems with centos rpm packages, and after correct cpanel system.

Comment: @abkrim - Yes. I got it correct from my provider. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have purchased a shared hosting service. There is nothing you can do to fix this error. Your hosting provider has to fix this issue.

Comment: You were right. I got a confirmation from my provider that there was an error in their server script. They've resolved it. By the way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue caused mainly due to incorrect permission issues for /bin/rpm . In our servers we have used [LES](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-environment-security/) and Seems that plugin is changing the permission of /bin/rpm to 700 and for cpanel we need to change that 755

Check the permission of /bin/rpm using the below command

## ls -l /bin/rpm

If it is having 700, then fix using the below command

## chmod 755 /bin/rpm

once changed simply refresh the page and you can see all is fixed